# multiple buttons to send predefined SMS

Tags: android, sms, onclicklistener

Hi guys i am new to programming. I am trying to have multiple button to send different predefined SMS to predefined number. I am not sure how to have multiple setOnClickListener(new `OnClickListener()` as the 2nd `setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()` gave me error. Without the "`buttonSend2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend2)`" the program works fine.

```
public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonSend;
    Button buttonSend2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        buttonSend2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend2);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        buttonSend2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.buttonSend:
                     Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                     sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "abc"); 
                     sendIntent.putExtra("address", "9909990");
                     sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                     startActivity(sendIntent);
                     break;

                case R.id.buttonSend2:
                    Intent sendIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                     sendIntent1.putExtra("sms_body", "def"); 
                     sendIntent1.putExtra("address", "012345678");
                     sendIntent1.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                     startActivity(sendIntent1);
                     break;
                }

            }
            });
        });
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your click listeners were a little confused. Try this:

```
buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
buttonSend2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend2);

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonSend:
             Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "abc"); 
             sendIntent.putExtra("address", "9909990");
             sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
             startActivity(sendIntent);
             break;

        case R.id.buttonSend2:
            Intent sendIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             sendIntent1.putExtra("sms_body", "def"); 
             sendIntent1.putExtra("address", "012345678");
             sendIntent1.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
             startActivity(sendIntent1);
             break;
        }

    }
};

buttonSend.setOnClickListener(listener);
buttonSend2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the reply. The program got 2 errors on me, 1 is at "Button "buttonSend2;" another 1 is at "buttonSend2.setOnClickListener(listener);" Both errors is the same: yntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody.

Comment: Tried to insert "}" at various spot but still doesn't work. sorry im a total newbie trying hard to learn

Comment: Thank you! its solved now. The code is working good. The problem just now was I forgot to add 2 more "{" in the end... was too focus on your code

Answer (score 0):

Ben Pearson's answer is totally valid, but I thought I'd leave an alternative in case it's easier for what you're doing.

You can have your activity class implement `View.onClickListener` and then simply have an `onClick(View v)` method in your class with a switch statement as above.

It's a very subtle difference, but if you're hiding or showing different clickable objects in different methods and don't want a class variable for an onClickListener, this implementation may work well for you.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative method